# On relative commutant inside crossed product

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $G$ be a discrete group acting on vN algebra $M$ in standard form. My question what is relative commutant of $M$ and $L(G)$ infact what is $M'\cap (M\rtimes G)$ and $L(G)'\cap(M\rtimes G)$?